# How to print all the links of a given url on a html file using django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, beautifulsoup

I have this code in my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def extract_links(request):
    starting_link = urllib.urlopen("http://www.finalyearondesk.com")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(starting_link)
    all_links = soup.findAll('a', href = True)          
    return render_to_response('extracted_links.html',{'all_links': all_links })
```

In this I am usign BeautifulSoup.
And i am writing this code in the template file: extracted_links.html:

```
{% for final_links in all_links %}
    {{ final_links['href'] }}    # {{ final_links.href }} did not print anything
{% endfor %}
```

But the problem is it shows an error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['href']' from 'final_links['href']'
```

Any suggestion how to solve this? If I use this function on a simple python file, it just works fine but not on django template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for final_links in all_links %}
   {{ final_links.attrMap.href }}
{% endfor %}
```

I arrived at that from the following session:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> start = urllib.urlopen('http://blog.tkbe.org')
>>> soup = BS(start)
>>> all_links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
>>> first = all_links[0]
>>> first
<a href="http://blog.tkbe.org/" title="TKBE" rel="home">TKBE</a>
>>> dir(first)
[..., 'attrMap', 'attrs', ...]
>>> first.attrs
[(u'href', u'http://blog.tkbe.org/'), (u'title', u'TKBE'), (u'rel', u'home')]
>>> first.attrMap
{u'href': u'http://blog.tkbe.org/', u'rel': u'home', u'title': u'TKBE'}
```

If your version of BeautifulSoup has other attributes you can find them similarly.

You might have to extract them in the view though, and not in the template, e.g.:

```
all_links = [link.attrMap['href'] for link in all_links]
```

before your return statement (or whichever attribute you need to access in your version of BeautifulSoup).

Comment: Still not printing anything on the html page..:(

Answer (score 1):

If `all_links` is a list of `dict`s each having key `href` then do the following to access the value of `href` in the Django template:

```
{% for final_links in all_links %}
    {{ final_links.href }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have done that already by learning that we can not put [] in {{ , but then it did not print anything on the html file

Comment: @AmitYadav What is the content of an individual item in your list `all_links`?

Comment: It is a list, as extracted by the find_all() method of beautiful soup

Comment: all_links contain lists element like: [<a href="http://someurl.com">link</a>, <a href="http://another.com">another link</a>,<a href="http://someurl.com">link</a>]

Comment: @AmitYadav The dot notation in Django templates accesses attributes of either objects or dictionaries. The `attrs` attribute of `BeautifulSoup` elements returns a `dict`. Therefore try: `{{ final_links.attrs.href }}`