# how to find image url from another domain url for meta og:image in django templates

Tags: python, django, markdown, meta

we have some problem to find image url another domain in django templates..
We use django markdown, and my `models.py` like this..

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("entry_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

I think, i can find image url from `{{ object.body.imgUrl }}`. but I know we havn't object to get `.imgUrl`.

So the there my problem, how to find image url from `object.body` but work if we use from another domain.

we've been looking for a way to find it, but until now still not found..
Thanks so much before..

**EDIT:**
I try with beautifulshoup like this in `views.py`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
@property
def _getUrl_Image(url_post):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_post)
    result = []
    for post in soup.select('div.post'):
        all_links = soup.findAll('img', src=True)
        first = all_links[0]
        string = str(first)
        split = string.split('"')
        result.append(split[3])

    return result[0]({'result' : result})
```

in templates.

```
{% for i in result %}
  {{ result }}
{% endfor %}
```

how to return `{{ result }}` in templates with value `url_post`

```
{% for i in result %}
  {{ result {% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug %} }}
{% endfor %}
```

I know it will be error.. :(

**EDIT 2:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def getUrlImage(url_post):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_post)
    result = []
    for post in soup.select('div.post'):
        all_links = soup.findAll('img', src=True)
        first = all_links[0]
        string = str(first)
        split = string.split('"')
        result.append(split[3])
    print result[0]
    return result[0]({'result' : result})
```

in templates:

```
{% load getUrlImage %}
{% for i in result %}
  {% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug as result_url %}
  {{ result }}{{ result_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

We have something error `Ups.. Error 500!`
are the server can't load my function or why?

Comment: You didn't explain, what imgUrl means. If this is a link in the text of the Entry.body, you can find your url with BeautifulSoap

Comment: ok, thank you sir.. maybe i can solved it like this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127421/3445802

Comment: Sir, i have something problem again to add field my function to call in templates..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're question is missing some important details but maybe the following will help you : for your last snippet write this instead (even if I don't know why you're using a for loop...):

```
{% for i in result %}
  {% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug as result_url %}
  {{ result }}{{ result_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: we try with ``@register.filter`` in my function, but we have an ``error 500`` if i try to reload my page..

Comment: I do not understand why you're trying to achieve...Could you be more specific ?

Comment: I want to take the first index of the image url from tag ``div.post``, and then call again into meta og:image as my title of question.. because we now use ``markdown``, in my admin post like this: http://imgur.com/sG0KvbW
that image from another domain..
how i can put it in my templates as ``og:image`` meta tags...